# Jasmine: How to see the reports in the browser?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

I am currently running AngularJs unit tests in the console.

I open the folder in the console and i run `karma start` and check the result of the tests in the console.

I would like to see the results in the browser but I cannot see them so far. All i can see is this:

[image]

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i see the reports of the tests in the browser?
The proper plugin should be karma-jasmine-html-reporter right?

**THE CONFIGURATION:**

karma.conf.js:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    './test/**/*.js',
    'app.js'
],

plugins : [
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-firefox-launcher',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'

],

browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
```

Comment: A descriptive [manual](https://novas1r1.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/add-karma-and-jasmine-to-an-existing-ionic-project/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have jasmine 2.0,

- add in `reporters: ['html'],` to your `karma.conf.js`
- In the chrome page hit the `DEBUG` button. You should be taken to a new page that has the report.