# Karma-Jasmine: Unexpected request: GET ... No more request expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

I am testing two different http calls in my AngularJs app.

There is a strange behavior. If i test each one separately, with the other temporary commented out (in the controller and in the test) each one works fine and the test passes.

But if I run karma when there are both the tests, they fail, giving the following error message:

```
Unexpected request: GET https://MY_DOMAIN_2.com/list_project
No more request expected
```

**THE CONTROLLER:**

```
.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.getLanguageList = function()
    {
        $http.get('http://MY_DOMAIN_1.org/languageList').then(function(resp) 
        {
            $scope.language_list = resp.data;
        }, 
        function(err) 
        {
            $scope.language_list = [];
        })
    }

    $scope.language_list = [];
    $scope.getLanguageList();


    $scope.get_project_list = function()
    {
        $http.get('https://MY_DOMAIN_2.com/projectList').then(function(resp) 
        {
            $scope.project_list = resp.data;
        }, 
        function(err) 
        {
            $scope.project_list = [];
        })
    }

    $scope.project_list = [];
    $scope.get_project_list();

})
```

**THE TEST:**

```
describe('Http requests tests', function() {

beforeEach(module('my_app.controllers'));

var $controller;
var $httpBackend;
var $scope;
var $timeout;


describe('Lists test', function() 
{

    beforeEach(angular.mock.http.init);
    afterEach(angular.mock.http.reset);

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_) 
    {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = {};
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    }));


    it('should load default language list', function (done) 
    {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://MY_DOMAIN_1.org/languageList').passThrough();

        var TestController = $controller('TestController', { $scope: $scope });

        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            expect($scope.language_list).not.toEqual([]);
            done();
        }, 1000);

    });


    it('should load default project list', function (done) 
    {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('https://MY_DOMAIN_2.org/projectList').passThrough();

        var TestController = $controller('TestController', { $scope: $scope });

        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            expect($scope.project_list).not.toEqual([]);
            done();
        }, 1000);

    });

});

});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why i am getting that error message?
The code should be fine since separately they are working fine. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: What if you changed your $scope = {} to $scope = $rootScope.$new()?

Comment: Have tried but nothing changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some pointers and a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/Kp9C4S6oNVu1MM1YLb90?p=preview

- You should be using `$httpBackend.flush()` and not `setTimeout()`.  This way you can control when your asynchronous request returns.  It makes it easier to test.
- Pull out your $httpBackend and controller into the beforeEach statement.  When your controller is created it fires off both url. Then you can evaluate it individually. When it is isolated in the `it` statement it does not call the other $http and throws the unexpected url error.
- You should also mock the response of your $http request and not passThrough.  You are not always going to have internet connection and the response can change. So make the mock data look like what you expect.
- In addition, `$httpBackend.whenGET('httpS://MY_DOMAIN_2.org/projectList')` is requesting the incorrect url.  It should be a lowercase `s` and a `.com` url. This is because the controller is requesting

  > $http.get('https://MY_DOMAIN_2.com/projectList')

Comment: Thank you very much! For the solution and clear explanation. About the last point, the S uppercase was a typo, but why should .com and not .org?

Comment: Btw here there is a question that i am sure you know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243100/jasmine-how-to-see-the-reports-in-the-browser

Comment: it should be `.com` because you called a `.com` in your controller.
`$http.get('https://MY_DOMAIN_2.com/projectList').then(function(resp) `

Answer (score 3):

Don't use timeouts, and test them at the same time:

```
it('should load default language list and the default project list', function (){
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://MY_DOMAIN_1.org/languageList').passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET('httpS://MY_DOMAIN_2.org/projectList').passThrough();

    var TestController = $controller('TestController', { $scope: $scope });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($scope.language_list).not.toEqual([]);
    expect($scope.project_list).not.toEqual([]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried but I am currently getting this error: No pending request to flush !

Comment: But following your suggestion to unite in a unique test is working! But only using timeout.. Why flush is not working properly? And why is working as a single test and not working as two separate tests.. ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add setTimeout and done property to your flush to prevent it

```
it('should get data in callback funcion', function (done) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/my-endpoint/).respond(mockDataResponse);

    apiFactory.getCurrencyFormat('en', function (res, err) {
        expect(res.a).to.deep.equal(generalMock.a);
        expect(res.b).to.deep.equal(generalMock.b);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        done();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }, 200);
});
```